# Fastest array lookup algorithm in C for embedded system?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, embedded

Let's say I have a constant array of floats with defined size 22 that looks like this:

```
array[0]= 0;
array[1]= 0.5;
array[2]= 0.7;
array[3]= 1.8;
...
...
array[21]= 4.2;
```

The values of this array are monotonic, this is, they always increase with the index ( array[0]<=array[1]<=array[2]<=....<=array[21] ).

And I want a function that given a float, it finds the index of the array whose value is immediately below the input float (and thus, the value of the next index is immediately above)

For example, in the previous case, if the input of the function is the value 0.68, the output of the function should be 1, since array[1]<= 0.68

Now, this is easy to implement, but i am dealing with a very time critical part of the code in an embedded system, and I really need a very optimized algorithm, that avoids loops (to avoid the overhead).

The simplest approach i am using now is just to unfold the loop with if-elses and that's it.

Example:

```
if(input >= array[size-1])
    return size-1;
else if(input>= array[size-2])
    return size-2;
else if(input >= array[size-3])
    return size-3;
...
...
```

But the problem here is that then I have jitter, since the path for different inputs take significantly different time.

So my question is: is there a fastest and more deterministic (less jitter) way to implement this?

Thank you.
Jorge.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a binary search is what you want.

Comment: Is there a way to normalize the float to an int and do a forward lookup?

Comment: This sounds tailor-made for a binary search (O(log n)).

Comment: Yes, you probabaly want binaray search here. What is `size`? Tens, hundreds, thousands? The bigger `size` is, the less unrolling the loop will matter.

Comment: The size of the array is 22

Comment: @JorgeS : You need to include that information in the question, not as a comment - people are using that information in their answers. The benefit of loop unrolling is possibly lost by the repeated evaluation of `size - n` (one for every failing condition, and two for success), a loop with a single increment index is likely to be faster and the compiler may unroll it in any case if optimisation is enabled.  If the size is truly fixed, then the use of the `size` variable is superfluous in any case.

Comment: If you need a very deterministic and constant time (in embedded most of the time being deterministic is more important than being fast) you also could use static hash table coz you specified that it's a constant array. Probably it will be a bit slower than BS but it will have constant time lookup.

Answer (score 7):

You get `O(log N)` if you use binary search:

```
size_t binaryFind(double x, double *array, size_t N) {
    size_t lower = 0;
    size_t upper = N;

    while (lower + 1 < upper) {
        mid = (lower + upper) / 2;
        if (x < array[mid]) {
            upper = mid;
        } else {
            lower = mid;
        }
    }
    if (array[lower] <= x) return lower;
    return (size_t)-1;
}
```

Notes:

`N` is the number of elements in array. Note that `array[N]` is outside the array. The array must be sorted in ascending order.

Return value will be `(size_t)-1` if `x` is smaller than `array[0]`. This is the equvalent of failure.

Return value will be `N-1` is `x` is larger than `array[N-1]`.

Comment: 90% of programmers can't write binary search! https://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/are-you-one-of-the-10-percent/

Comment: @JulianCienfuegos In that case I don't have to be embarrased over not completing it in 2 minutes. I have fixed the termination criteria and the return value (my intuition was correct - there were problems with both). Still haven't dared to compile it, though.

Answer (score 3):

The solution posted below uses binary search (logarithmic time complexity). To learn more about floating point numbers comparison please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5989278/2429333).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ACCURACY 0.0001

int float_cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    float *a_f = (float *)a;
    float *b_f = (float *)b;
    float diff = *a_f - *b_f;
    if (diff > ACCURACY) return 1;
    else if (diff < -ACCURACY) return -1;
    else return 0;
}

size_t find(void *arr, size_t nitems, size_t size, void *val,  int (*compare)(const void *, const void*)){

    if (nitems < 1) return -1;
    else if (nitems == 1 && (compare(arr, val) == 0)) return 0;

    size_t lower = 0;
    size_t upper = nitems;

    while (upper - lower > 1){
        size_t id = (lower + upper) / 2;
        int cmp = compare(arr + size*id, val);
        if      (cmp == 0) return id;
        else if (cmp > 1)  upper = id;
        else               lower = id;
    }

    return -1;
}

float arr[] = {
    5.5,
    6.6,
    9.9,
    10.01,
    10.05,
    10.10,
};

int main(){
    float val = 10.10;
    size_t i = find(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), sizeof(float), &val ,float_cmp);
    printf("index: %zu\n", i);
}
```

Comment: A straight binary search is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Yes I realized that too late, I'm considering deleting this answer as the edition comes down to exactly what you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

A linear search would actually be branchless (provided your µC has a conditional move)

```
int resultIdx = -1
for (size_t i = 0; i != 22; ++i)
  if (array[i] < testvalue) resultIdx = i;
```

Your compiler will probably unroll this loop, make the assignment of the result conditional, and probably to a register. Furthermore, as it will continue iterating over the array, it will also be jitter free.

Answer (score 0):

If it's *extreme time critical* then you could build it completly with `IF/ELSE` for the fixed 22 elements.
You only have to unroll the [sample of Klas Lindbäck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42906172/463115).

But it seems more important to avoid the floats.
Use integers instead, the conversion rule could be `(int)(floatValue*1000)`, but this depends of your required precision and number range.